# Cloud9 IDE Main Menu Bar (File, Edit, Run, etc.) stuck minimized?

Tags: drop-down-menu, ide, submenu, cloud9-ide, google-chrome-os

I've seemed to minimize the Main Menu Bar (not the specific term), resting at the top, or ceiling, in the Cloud9 IDE. There's a small drop-down arrow located on the top-center and you'd think that would be indicative of bringing it back down or something, but I'm getting no functionality out of my numerous, calculated clicks.

I've tried to enlarging it no avail, refreshing the URL, copy command, etc. and to my very little knowledge, surprisingly, have had no success. I'm using ChromeOS, if to supply any more assistance. Any ideas? Thanks for reading if you got this far, I sure do appreciate it.

Answer (score 15):

Click on the thin empty space right at the top of the window and the bar will re-appear.

Answer (score 9):

The arrow in the top center of the screen should show the File menu again. Try opening up the IDE in an incognito window to make sure no browser extensions are interfering.

If this doesn't work, you may try appending `?reset=1` to your workspace URL. Be warned that this will reset all your workspace settings, such as themes, keybindings, etc. This should reset your workspace layout as well.

Answer (score 0):

The answer above is correct. The mouse will change to a hand once you click right above the top line. Tricky one.